# Why the rush to delete migrateable SuperUser questions?

Tags: discussion, migration, deleted-questions

Given that a migration feature is [planned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52141/will-it-be-possible-to-migrate-questions-between-the-trilogy-and-the-stack-exchan), why the rush to delete questions that will qualify for this? Can we not just leave these questions closed and migrate them when this the migration feature is available? Some of these questions (yes, a few of these were mine) have a lot of good content that is being lost.

Comment: +1. Totally agree and was going to ask about the same thing. (Having posted a Gmail question that had been around for 10 months, with a few upvotes, and was closed and deleted only this July when possibility to migrate to Webapps was already really close.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No rush really. Just trying to clean SU up from all the migrated out and off-topic questions that are just hanging around like a bad smell.

Been meaning to do it for a while. Timing wasn't considered beyond how long a question has been festering, so those with at least a couple of months were the first to burn.

They can later be undeleted and migrated whenever that option comes around. And seeing as there is no guarantee that any SE site currently will live, that's up in the air.

They can also be accessed if you download the [Creative Commons Data Dump for SU](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/). If a bulk of deletion is happening in one particular month, you should be able to download the month before that to see and reuse, with attribution, the data and posts from it.

Which may be handy if you want to cherry-pick through questions and answers to repost on the new Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Sounds good -- I was under the impression that deleted questions were unrecoverable after a certain amount of time had lapsed.

Comment: I agree with @random, it will clean up Super User quite a bit...

Comment: Fair enough that you are actually willing to undelete for migration (that's not the impression a non-meta reading user gets when he finds his stuff gone). Problem is that it's very unlikely that people know to suggest this, when they can't find *any* trace of the question they (or someone else) posted long ago (except from Google cache if they're lucky). Most users are not going to dig into data dumps for this (actually, most users aren't even *aware* of such things).